# Can't paste (Command+V) into an NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, copy-paste, nstextfield

For some reason, an NSTextField isn't allowing me to paste anything into it using `Command+V`, though I can paste into it if I right-click and click 'Paste'. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it by linking the "Paste" button in my NSMenu Main Menu to the First Responder's `paste:` command.

Comment: That's a menu item (NSMenuItem), not a button (NSButton), and an action message selector, not a command (HICommand).

Comment: There must me more to it than this... I've re-added the IB's standard "Menu Item - Edit" and all the commands in there are correctly linked to the First Responder. But still not getting any keyboard commands. Am I not linking up the "Menu Item - Edit" correctly?

Comment: do you have exampe of how you did this?

Comment: I had accidentally deleted my NSEdit menu, adding back in via Interface Builder fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to this
[Making copy & paste work with NSTextField](https://blog.kulman.sk/making-copy-paste-work-with-nstextfield/)

```
final class EditableNSTextField: NSTextField {

private let commandKey = NSEvent.ModifierFlags.command.rawValue
private let commandShiftKey = NSEvent.ModifierFlags.command.rawValue | NSEvent.ModifierFlags.shift.rawValue

override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
    if event.type == NSEvent.EventType.keyDown {
        if (event.modifierFlags.rawValue & NSEvent.ModifierFlags.deviceIndependentFlagsMask.rawValue) == commandKey {
            switch event.charactersIgnoringModifiers! {
            case "x":
                if NSApp.sendAction(#selector(NSText.cut(_:)), to: nil, from: self) { return true }
            case "c":
                if NSApp.sendAction(#selector(NSText.copy(_:)), to: nil, from: self) { return true }
            case "v":
                if NSApp.sendAction(#selector(NSText.paste(_:)), to: nil, from: self) { return true }
            case "z":
                if NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("undo:")), to: nil, from: self) { return true }
            case "a":
                if NSApp.sendAction(#selector(NSResponder.selectAll(_:)), to: nil, from: self) { return true }
            default:
                break
            }
        } else if (event.modifierFlags.rawValue & NSEvent.ModifierFlags.deviceIndependentFlagsMask.rawValue) == commandShiftKey {
            if event.charactersIgnoringModifiers == "Z" {
                if NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("redo:")), to: nil, from: self) { return true }
            }
        }
    }
    return super.performKeyEquivalent(with: event)
}
```

}

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you've removed the "Edit" menu (for example when making a menu-app) you need to re-implement this back. I have used `extension` of NSTextField instead to allow SwiftUIs TextField and TextEditor to work out of hte box, but this is sufficient too.

Comment: Can you please tell me how this works and where can I place this code

Comment: I implemented tableview programatically. I am not sure about this edit Menu

Comment: just add this class to your code, select the NSTextFiled, in the identity inspector assign this class

Answer (score 4):

What happens when you select "Edit > Paste" from your application's main menu?

Comment: My application sits in the menu bar, it doesn't have a main menu. Could that be the reason? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Yes, you need something map your keyboard commands to actions (like paste:), and to map the actions to the First Responder.  Setting up a menu is the easiest way to do that.  Even if you app's Dock icon and menu bar are hidden, you main menu will still receive keyboard commands.

Comment: I made a main menu for my application now, but now when I click "Edit", the "Paste" button and all others are grayed out even why my cursor is in a text field. How do I fix this?

Comment: Chetan: You need to hook up the menu items to First Responder.

Answer (score 3):

Did you:

- Assign a key equivalent to any of
  your controls (NSButtons,
  NSMenuItems, ...) that are responding
  before the Main Menu

-- or --

- Delete the whole Menu
- the Edit NSMenuItem
- the Paste NSMenuItem
  The "Paste" Shortcut is a key equivalent of the "Paste" NSMenuItem

Comment: I have that problem too. Initially I have removed the Edit menu (because no need for it in the first), but later I had to reimplement it fro IB: all is working, everything works except 'paste'. the relative action in first responder is there, what can be the problem?